# Blank window while using synchronized blocks in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm developing a java application with windows. I want to make a confirmation window to be displayed when actions like "add friend" are launched. In my main window I have a method with this code:

```
public Boolean confirmQuestion(String question) {
    synchronized (this) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                confirmationFrame.setMessage(question);
                confirmationFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }.start();
        System.err.println(question);
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return confirmationFrame.getAnswer();
    }
}
```

Well, as you can supose, confirmationFrame is the class used as additional frame. I instantiated it in the constructor (as it is a final attribute). It has the following code to handle the accept button:

```
    private void acceptButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    answer = true;
    this.setVisible(false);
    synchronized (main) {
        main.notify();
    }
}
```

And the problem is that when I don't call the this.wait() in the main frame, the confirmation window displays correctly, with buttons and all the stuff, but when I use the previous code, the confirmation window is empty, it's created just with a title and can't be closed.

Why when I'm making the principal frame thread wait it crashes? The additional frame should work, it is in another thread...

Comment: ok, some basic things: 1. the implementation of the confirmationFrame is missing. 2. use new Thread(() -> {/*your code*/}).start() instead of overriding Thread.

Comment: You are synchronising on main, and then, whilst holding the lock, you are trying to synchronise on it from another thread.

Comment: This looks quite weird, you do stuff with Swing from random threads - its strongly recommened *not* to instantiate Swing objects or call methods from threads other than the Swing thread (have a look at SwingUtilities.invokeLater/invokeAndWait). From an architecture standpoint, its also weird, for a modal interface you use a *dialog*, not a frame. JDialog has the added benefit of blocking the method that calls setVisible(true), so there would be *no need* to deal with that manually.

Comment: confirmationFrame implementation is so big due to all the graphical stuff generated by Netbeans. What should I upload too? The constructor?

Comment: In addition to the other issues noted, you should not be using wait/notify. In general, use higher level concurrency utilities. In your case, use JOptionPane or JDialog like others have mentioned and avoid this problem altogether. See Effective Java, Item #69.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way to show dialogs using Java. You should look into JOptionPanes in order to display pop-up dialogs.

There are various forms of JOptionPane's you can use to get input, confirmations, show dialogs, etc.

Documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

If you want to customize the JOptionPane you can pass it a custom JPanel as follows:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,panel,"Added Friend",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: I started little time ago with swing development and I don't know yet all its capabilities. This is perfect for my program. Thanks!